# Javascript in Controller Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

Is it possible to have a javascript code in the controller? I'm trying to have an alert if the login failed,

here is the condition in my controller:

```
public function login2()
{
    if(!empty($_POST['btn_login'])){
        $session_login = $this->inventory_model->select_login($this->input->post());
        if($session_login){
            $this->session->set_userdata('login_session', 
                array(
                    'Username' => $session_login->Username,
                    'Password' => $session_login->Password,
                    'UserType' => $session_login->UserType
                )
            );
            redirect('inventorysys_controller/homepage');
        }
        else{
            echo "Invalid Username/Password!";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to put the javascript in the else, so is it possible guys?

Here is my view in case you need a reference:

```
<form action="login2" method="POST" id="log_form" name="log_form" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="container">     
          <div id="nav_log1">
            Username: <input type="text" id="txt_user1" name="txt_user1" style="color: black;"/>
            Password: <input type="password" id="txt_pass1" name="txt_pass1" style="color: black;"/>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- /container -->
    <div class="modal-footer" style="padding: 20px; margin-top: 20px;">
        <button type="submit" value="login" id="btn_login" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="btn_login">Sign-In</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <!--<button id="close_me" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>-->
    </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Your help will be truly appreciated. :)

Comment: `echo "<script>alert('Invalid Username/Password!');</script>";`

Comment: I've tried it, the alert pops up but it is on another blank page not on the login page.

Comment: It'll be doing it on a blank page because your view which contains your actual page display won't have been loaded before you alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using alerts, if you are using codeigniter try flashdata.

syntax :

To add flashdata:

```
 $this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value');
```

To read a flashdata variable:

```
 $this->session->flashdata('item');
```

as per you code :

controller :

```
public function login2()
{
if(!empty($_POST['btn_login'])){
    $session_login = $this->inventory_model->select_login($this->input->post());
    if($session_login){
        $this->session->set_userdata('login_session', 
            array(
                'Username' => $session_login->Username,
                'Password' => $session_login->Password,
                'UserType' => $session_login->UserType
            )
        );
        redirect('inventorysys_controller/homepage');
    }
    else{
        //echo "Invalid Username/Password!";
         $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Invalid Username/Password!');
        redirect('inventorysys_controller/login_page');
    }
}
}
```

View:

```
<form action="login2" method="POST" id="log_form" name="log_form" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <div>
            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');?>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="container">     
          <div id="nav_log1">
            Username: <input type="text" id="txt_user1" name="txt_user1" style="color: black;"/>
            Password: <input type="password" id="txt_pass1" name="txt_pass1" style="color: black;"/>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- /container -->
    <div class="modal-footer" style="padding: 20px; margin-top: 20px;">
        <button type="submit" value="login" id="btn_login" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="btn_login">Sign-In</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <!--<button id="close_me" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>-->
    </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: I have a parent construct, should I put the $this->session->flashdata('item','value') in there? And I don't know where to put $this->session->flashdata('item'); Sorry sir, I've tried flashdata before but it didn't work, maybe I did put the codes in the wrong place.

Comment: 'item' is just name here in my answer i used 'msg'. please look my answer. Alert is not a good idea.

Comment: It is not working for me sir, It just redirect on the login page no flash data popping up.

Comment: It is working, my bad sir, but it's just text, I don't know how to have buttons on that div, and how can I make it look like a message box.

Answer (score 2):

Your best and most CodeIgniter/MVC friendly way to do this would be to assign your error message to a variable and then alert it in your view...

```
public function login2(){
    $data = array();
    if(!empty($_POST['btn_login'])){
        $session_login = $this->inventory_model->select_login($this->input->post());
        if($session_login){
            $this->session->set_userdata('login_session', array('Username' => $session_login->Username,
                                                                'Password' => $session_login->Password,
                                                                'UserType' => $session_login->UserType));
                                                            redirect('inventorysys_controller/homepage');
        }
        else{
            // echo "Invalid Username/Password!";
            $data['error'] = 'Invalid Username/Password!';
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('your-view', $data);
}
```

In your view:

```
if (isset($error) && !empty($error)) {
    echo "<script>alert('" . $error . "')</script>";
}
```

Comment: Solved it! Thank you for the help! But the url of my page is changing probably because of the <form action="login2"> in my view but I think I can fix that. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display javascript from PHP, do the following:

```
echo "<script>alert('login failed');</script>";
```

Or more preferrably, build your app in a restful way, that means use ajax requests, to fetch data in probably JSON format from a server (your controller in this case) :)

Hope it helps, in case of any questions, i am here!